# Path of xml file responsible for displaying pivot Day/ Week/ Month/ ..?

Tags: odoo

The modul responsible for logic is in _read_group_process_groupby method (server\openerp\models.py),

but I can not find xml file, any idea please?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

That will be written on the **web** module.

Path = `web/static/src/xml/base.xml`

Template name - `PivotView.GroupBySelection`

You can find here, this is for **odoo-13** version [Click Here](https://github.com/odoo/odoo/blob/13.0/addons/web/static/src/xml/base.xml#L480)

```xml
<t t-name="PivotView.GroupBySelection">
    <div class="dropdown-menu o_pivot_field_menu" role="menu">
        <t t-foreach="fields" t-as="field">
            <t t-if="(field[1].type === 'date') || (field[1].type === 'datetime')">
                <div role="menuitem" aria-haspopup="true" class="o_inline_dropdown">
                    <a href="#" t-att-data-field="field[0]" t-attf-class="dropdown-item o_pivot_field_selection#{field[2] ? ' disabled' : ''}">
                        <t t-esc="field[1].string"/>
                    </a>
                    <div class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
                        <a role="menuitem" href="#" class="dropdown-item" t-att-data-interval="'day'" t-att-data-field="field[0]">Day</a>
                        <a role="menuitem" href="#" class="dropdown-item" t-att-data-interval="'week'" t-att-data-field="field[0]">Week</a>
                        <a role="menuitem" href="#" class="dropdown-item" t-att-data-interval="'month'" t-att-data-field="field[0]">Month</a>
                        <a role="menuitem" href="#" class="dropdown-item" t-att-data-interval="'quarter'" t-att-data-field="field[0]">Quarter</a>
                        <a role="menuitem" href="#" class="dropdown-item" t-att-data-interval="'year'" t-att-data-field="field[0]">Year</a>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </t>
            <t t-else="">
                <a href="#" role="menuitem" t-att-data-field="field[0]" t-attf-class="dropdown-item#{field[2] ? ' disabled' : ''}"><t t-esc="field[1].string"/></a>
            </t>
        </t>
    </div>
</t>
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

In odoo8 it is located in 
server\addons\web_graph\static\src\xml\web_graph.xml